# How to RewriteRule WITH and WITHOUT parameters in htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-parameters

I want to route all .php and .html files to a certain php file wether they have URL parameters or not.

Example:

```
www.mydomain.com/mysite.php?par1=test 
www.mydomain.com/intro.html?nopar=1
```

Idea:

```
RewriteRule \.(?:php|html)$ work.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close, just add a condition to avoid rewriting if request is already for `work.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/work\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(?:php|html)$ work.php [L,NC]
```

Note that query string is automatically carried over to target URI.